# No comprendo el resultado del test en jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jest

Estoy aprendiendo testing con jest y en uno de los ejercicios debía craer una función que como parámetro recibiera un solo argumento, en este caso un array vació. El test debía comprobar que esa condición se cumpliera.

**La función es la siguiente:**

```
    const dummy = (blogs) => {
      return  arguments.length
    }

    module.exports = {
     dummy
    }
```

**y el test que debe comprobar el resultado es el siguiente**

```
const listHelper = require('../utils/list_helper')

  test('dummy returns one', () => {
    const blogs = []
    const result = listHelper.dummy(blogs)
    expect(result).toBe(1)
  })
```

**pero por alguna razon el resultado es 6 y lo esperado es 1. Y no comprendo la falla**

Comment: que estas devolviendo al poner arguments.length y porque esperas 1 de resultado?

Comment: con arguments.length devuelvo la cantidad de parámetros que le paso a la función. Espero que sea 1 por que solo le paso un parámetro que es el array blogs.

Comment: `dummy` es una [función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), por lo cual tomará los argumentos del padre, ya que `this` no apunta a la función flecha. Las funciones `flecha` se comportan diferente que las funciones declaradas con `function`.

Comment: Si asi como te dijo @MauricioContreras, debes hacerlo con una funcion declarada con 'function'